# MYSQL - Stored Procedure Query Simplify

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am new to MYSQL.

I need to customize this query. Now I am using only the IF condition and the query length is too big.

In this stored procedure only we change 'f.status' value based on _status value

EX:

__status  = 'ALL'

```
ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=0;
```

__status  = 'PAID'

```
ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=1;
```

__status  = 'UNPAID'

ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=2;

**Query:**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `all_data_search`(
_status VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    IF (_status='All') THEN
    SELECT
    f.financeId,
    f.customerId,
    c.customerName,
    c.initial,
    c.phone1,
    c.aadhaar,
    f.financeStartDate,
    f.vehicleNumber,
    f.loanAmount,
    f.totalInstallment,
    f.installmentAmount,
    COALESCE(t.payedInstallment, 0) as payedInstallment,
    f.status,
    f.created_by,
    f.created_date,
    f.updated_by,
    f.updated_date
FROM finance f
INNER JOIN customer c
    ON c.customerId = f.customerId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT financeId, COUNT(status) AS payedInstallment
    FROM financeinstallment
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY financeId
) t
    ON f.financeId = t.financeId;
    END IF;
    IF (_status='0') THEN
        SELECT
    f.financeId,
    f.customerId,
    c.customerName,
    c.initial,
    c.phone1,
    c.aadhaar,
    f.financeStartDate,
    f.vehicleNumber,
    f.loanAmount,
    f.totalInstallment,
    f.installmentAmount,
    COALESCE(t.payedInstallment, 0) as payedInstallment,
    f.status,
    f.created_by,
    f.created_date,
    f.updated_by,
    f.updated_date
FROM finance f
INNER JOIN customer c
    ON c.customerId = f.customerId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT financeId, COUNT(status) AS payedInstallment
    FROM financeinstallment
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY financeId
) t
    ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=0;
    END IF;
    IF (_status = 'PAID') THEN
    SELECT
    f.financeId,
    f.customerId,
    c.customerName,
    c.initial,
    c.phone1,
    c.aadhaar,
    f.financeStartDate,
    f.vehicleNumber,
    f.loanAmount,
    f.totalInstallment,
    f.installmentAmount,
    COALESCE(t.payedInstallment, 0) as payedInstallment,
    f.status,
    f.created_by,
    f.created_date,
    f.updated_by,
    f.updated_date
FROM finance f
INNER JOIN customer c
    ON c.customerId = f.customerId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT financeId, COUNT(status) AS payedInstallment
    FROM financeinstallment
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY financeId
) t
    ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=1;
     END IF;
     IF (_status = 'UNPAID') THEN
    SELECT
    f.financeId,
    f.customerId,
    c.customerName,
    c.initial,
    c.phone1,
    c.aadhaar,
    f.financeStartDate,
    f.vehicleNumber,
    f.loanAmount,
    f.totalInstallment,
    f.installmentAmount,
    COALESCE(t.payedInstallment, 0) as payedInstallment,
    f.status,
    f.created_by,
    f.created_date,
    f.updated_by,
    f.updated_date
FROM finance f
INNER JOIN customer c
    ON c.customerId = f.customerId
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT financeId, COUNT(status) AS payedInstallment
    FROM financeinstallment
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY financeId
) t
    ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=2;
     END IF;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Optimize or simplify?

Comment: simplify..........

Comment: `ON f.financeId = t.financeId where f.status=FIND_IN_SET(_status, 'ALL,PAID,UNPAID') - 1;` or the same using CASE function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare status_flag smallint;
....

 IF (_status = 'ALL') THEN status_flag=0;
 ELSEIF (_status = 'PAID') THEN status_flag=1;
 ELSEIF (_status = 'UNPAID') THEN status_flag=2;
 ENDIF;

 ....
 WHERE status = status_flag
```

Comment: Excess variable and no profit. CASE function in the query directly is more useful.

Comment: Akina: Could you please answer my question

Comment: I need the Just WHERE condition dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean operation as follows:

```
ON f.financeId = t.financeId 
where (__status = 'ALL' and f.status=0)
   or (__status = 'PAID' and f.status=1)
   or (__status = 'UNPAID' and f.status=2);
```